# CAML query order by not being applied with SpServices GetListItems

Tags: spservices, caml

I am trying to use SP Services to get a filtered and sorted list of data. My service call looks like this.

```
var query = "<Query>" +
                "<Where>" +
                    "<Eq>" +
                        "<FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Text'>Active</Value>" +
                    "</Eq>" +
                "</Where>" +
                "<OrderBy>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='Order' />" +
                "</OrderBy>" +
            "</Query>";

var viewFields = "<ViewFields>" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='Title' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='backgroundImage' />" +
                    "<FieldRef Name='link' />" +
                "</ViewFields>";

$().SPServices({
    operation: "GetListItems",
    webURL: "a/url/",
    async: true,
    listName: "Slider",
    CAMLQuery: query,
    CAMLViewFields: viewFields,
    completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
        var slides = [];
        $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
            slides.push({
                title: $(this).attr("ows_Title"),
                bgImage: $(this).attr("ows_backgroundImage"),
                link: $(this).attr("ows_link"),
            });
        });
        callback(slides);
    }
});
```

The problem I am having is that the where clause is being applied, but the order by is not. I have tried wrapping the  node in a  node as suggested in this post: [Caml Query for Order By List for web service call not ordering](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12140/caml-query-for-order-by-list-for-web-service-call-not-ordering) .  This gave me an internal server error.

I have also tried removing the Query tag entirely. Can anyone see why the order by clause is not being applied? This gave me a bad request error.

The Order field is a number typed column.

EDIT (solution):

My problem was that I named my list column 'Order' which apparently is implicitly created. Sharepoint renamed my column 'Order0' without me knowing. I ended up deleting my original column and creating a new one called 'slideOrder'

Comment: Can you add an `Ascending='True'`  into `"<FieldRef Name='Order' />"`, for example `"<FieldRef Name='Order' Ascending='True'/>"`, and see if that works?

Comment: Sadly that did not work. Thanks for the attempt though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a direct answer but here are some steps you can do to troubleshoot:

- Try removing the View Fields from the SPServices Call
- Try adding a rowlimit like this:

  ```
  CAMLRowLimit: 1,
  ```
- Try OrderBy on another field such as Title to see if that works
- Try the query with just the OrderBy element
- Ensure 'Order' is the Internal name of your field and is type of Number or Text
- Consider using REST API instead of SPServices

Comment: Bullet number 5 was the correct answer. Apparently the name 'Order' was already taken so it implicitly renamed my 'Order0'. Deleted the column and made a new one called 'slideOrder'.

Comment: yeah sounded like there was a conflict there. Glad you got it